# Differentiating Application Upload and FTP Client uploads

Tags: amazon-s3

Assume we have an web application where user will be provided an option to upload folder/file

Assume we have created an IAM and configured FTP to access S3 via FTP.

Now the user can upload a folder/file via FTP or web application.

We need to create a event notification or call a rest api whenever a new folder or file has been uploaded.

1. How to register an event register and call the rest API whenever a new folder or file has been uploaded?
2. How to differentiate whether the upload or file has been done from web application or FTP server from S3 ?

We need to call a different api when the folder has been created via web application and we need to call a different api when the folder has been created via FTP server

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can register to an object created event using lambda function via the properties of the bucket(ObjectCreated(All) event), and then execute a call to your API.

2) You can add a metadata to you file while uploading it saving the source of the upload. For example in your http request add the following header x-amz-meta-filesource. Every header starting with x-amz-meta- will be saved as the file metadata.